# The trading team was disbanded. Is this sentence idiomatic?

Tags: idiom-request

The situation is this: A trading team made a big loss and was broken up. And all the team members get fired.

I want to tell this situation to others.

What would be the best word for the blank to express the situation?

> The trading team was ___________.

I could think of words such as disbanded, broken up, dissolved, dispersed, etc. But I'm not sure what word or phrase would be the most idiomatic.

Comment: Please tell us the source of the first quote. Please check it carefullly as it contains errors.

Comment: @JamesK I made it by myself.

Comment: Okay,  check "were all get fired".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestions are all acceptable, but "disbanded" or "broken up" seem most likely.  "Dispersed" suggests that the team members were actually sent to different physical locations.

In the actual example, do you need to say that the team was disbanded?  If the team members were all fired then the team must be broken up in the process. So the simplest way to say this:

> The trading team made a big loss, so the team members were all fired.

Comment: I see. The 'get fired' is not idiomatic?

Comment: You say either "I was fired" or "I got fired" but not "I was got fired".

Comment: That's right. I didn't notice I was speaking in wrong English.

Comment: The terms “sacked”, “let go”, or “given the boot” would be idiomatic if you did not want to use the words fired or terminated.